# Why isAuthorized() is never called when running Controller tests?

Tags: cakephp, testing, authentication, controller, phpunit

Im trying to test authorization in one of my controllers to make sure that only certains kind of user can access some actions. But the isAuthorized() method on AppController is never called when running tests. This is how the method looks like:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null){
    if(!isset($this->request->params['admin'])){
        return true;
    }

    return in_array($user['role'], array('admin', 'root'));
}
```

My test function:

```
public function testArticlesIndex() {
    $this->generate('Articles', array(
        'components' => array('Auth')
    ));

    $this->testAction('/admin/articles', array('return' => 'view'));
    $this->assertEmpty($this->view);
}
```

I tried a lot of stuff mocking AuthComponent and not mocking it. I couldnt get a way to reproduce this situation, which would require isAuthorized(), where a user with a role other than admin or root tries to access an action on admin and fails.

Comment: How do you mock the current session user then? I think the cleanest way is to test isAuthorized directly with mocked params / a mocked request.

Answer (score 0):

When you mock the Auth component without defining what methods to mock, by default, all methods are mocked. The solution would be to mock the particular AuthComponent method you wish to mock:

```
 $this->generate('Articles', array(
   'components' => array(
     'Auth' => array(
       'redirect' // only mocks AuthComponent::redirect()
     )
   )
 ));
```

From the book:

> You can choose to stub an entire class by not passing methods to it,
>   like Session in the example above.

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction